# How can I let a user set logging level after import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-import

What I am trying to accomplish is allowing a user to change the logging level after an import.

My current directory structure is:

```
foo/
    bar.py
myapp.py
```

Inside `bar.py` I have the following code.

```
import logging

def log_stuff(level):
    l = getattr(logging, level.upper(), None)
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s \n%(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S',
                    level=l)
```

Inside `myapp.py` I have the following code:

```
from foo.bar import *    
log_level = None
if log_level is None:
    log_stuff('info')
    print log_level
else:
    log_stuff(log_level)
    print log_level

class SOMECLASS:
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

What I am trying to do is when I use `myapp`, I want the ability to change the log level as such:

```
import myapp
myapp.log_level = 'debug'
```

My issue is that this is printing `None`. The variable is not changing. The logging is always printing info and not debug.

I admit my code structure could be completely off, but I would really like the ability to change the logging level after importing `myapp`

Comment: instead `if __name__ = '__main__':`  it should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: Thank you @MaheshKaria. It was a typo when I posted here. I corrected it.

Comment: Your code behaves correctly. When you call `import myapp`, the `log_level` is set to `None` and the logging is configured with it. **After** the import, you set `log_level` to `INFO`, but it has no effect since logging was already configured on import.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. Any suggestions on how I can get it to behave the way I need it? Which is to be able to set the logging level after import?